# reading Associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array...generated from this code.

```
$aa = new_Arr();

print_r($aa);   //here is the result...


     cl_aa Object
    (
        [data:cl_aa:private] => Array
            (
                [t_a] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [f_c] => LAL
                                [p_r] => RN
                                [id] => 1214125
                                [gender] => m
                            )
                    )

                [t_b] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [t_l] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [p_lev] => 2
                                [p_date] => 
                                [p_r] => 
                            )
                    )

                [t_r] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [I_r] => 19
                            )

                    )

            )

        [db:cl_aa:private] => PDOTester Object
            (
            )
    )
```

I try to read it as like this...

```
foreach ($aa as $key=>$value) {
     print_r($key);
     echo "<h1>". $value['bb']. "</h1>";
 }
```

but no result i can see...

how do I read the above array? Help please?

Comment: If your objects are private, you can't access them from outside their class without getters.

Comment: Make them public for example?

Comment: Either make them public or create getters in your class. I suggest you have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: The difference with getters would be that the values cannot be changed outside of the given class (without any setters). Decision between public and getters will be based on your particular case.

Comment: there is no way to change from private to public, some other idea please?

Comment: As said already, provide `cl_aa` with getters for the values you need.

Comment: Where you get the result give me the link. we analyze and give you the solution

Comment: what is that getters means? please explain a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide your `cl_aa` class some getters :

```
public class cl_aa {

    private $data;
    private $db;

    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
    public function getDb() {
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

And to access your data from outside :

```
$aa = new_Arr(); // I assume this function returns a cl_aa object.
print_r($aa->getData());
print_r($aa->getDb());
```

Take a look at [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) to learn more about OOP.

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem...the getter Method..Thanks Mr.Yellow Bird. you really are yellow...ohhhhh, thanks anyway...